# Does kerbtray.exe not exist for windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, kerberos

I can not find a valid kerbtray.exe for windows server 2008. I can only find for 2000 and 2003. Does it not exist or it is just replaced with something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is not a 2008 version.  However, you can use the 2003 version on 2008 without issue.

The download can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9D467A69-57FF-4AE7-96EE-B18C4790CFFD&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 7):

There is command line tool called `klist` which ships with the OS.

Comment: This is right answer. Example:  klist get HTTP/yourhost.yourdomain.com

Comment: good info, additional to above comment with get should be `klist get "HTTP/tsoapp11.hq.tsosol.com@HQ.TSOSOL.COM"`